# Dell U2713HM LCD Monitor Killing Wifi (and ethernet) on my Mid-2012 MBP and iPhone 4S

Tags: wifi, display, displayport

I just purchased a Dell U2713HM monitor.

As soon as the monitor is turned on, the internet (both wifi and wired) goes out.

I have tried the following fixes:

1) Changing channels on wifi router.

2) Changing display resolutions. Very low resolutions bring the internet back (on both cable and wifi).

3) Different ways of hooking the display up to my Mac (directly via a Mini-displayport to displayport cable or by first connecting a mini-displayport to regular displayport adapter and then hooking the monitor up to that).

4) Trying to find settings in the monitor's OSD that may account for the strange behavior.

Any and all help is very appreciated.

*Thank you very much!*

Comment: What cable do you use ? Did you install the Dell software?

Comment: Hi Buscar, at the moment, I'm using a mini displayport to displayport cable connected from the thunderbolt port on the mac directly to the displayport adapter on the monitor. Dell does not make any additional software for Macs--just for PCs.

Answer (score 1):

I want to post a quick update as I have been able to isolate the problem.

My MBP's magsafe power adapter was hooked-up to the same power strip into which my Dell display was plugged into.

Plugging the magsafe into a "discrete" power outlet solved the wifi blackout issue.

I hope this helps others dealing with similar issues...